# Do I need to override my virtual function using an inherited object (vs. base object)?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, public

Say I have a base `class Base`, and two derived classes `Derived: public Base` and `Derived2: public Base`.
I have a purely virtual function

```
virtual int CompareByInsertKey( Base* item_in_list ) = 0;
```

In class `Base`. So it's a function that takes a pointer to a `Base` class.

I want my class `Derived` to overwrite this virtual function but I want it to take a pointer to a `Derived` class as an argument.
I also want my class `Derived2` to overwrite this function but I want to to take a pointer to the `Derived2` class as an argument. 
Does it do this automatically if I keep the argument as `Base* item_in_list` because `Derived` and `Derived2` are part `Base` classes?
If not, how do I do this?

Thanks, if you need me to post more information, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it takes pointers to the derived classes automatically because `Derived *` is implicitly convertible to `Base *`. You will have to implement it using Base in the function argument in order to override the function though.

```
virtual int CompareByInsertKey( Base* item_in_list ) override
{
    Derived *ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(item_in_list);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok so if I leave it as a pointer to the base class it will work?

Comment: @ASASAQQQQ yeah, as long as you cast it back to the derived class if you need anything that's not in the base class

Comment: How do I cast it back to the derived class? I have members that it needs to access but I can't change the method arguments

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot do what are hoping to do.

```
struct Base
{
   virtual int CompareByInsertKey( Base* item ) = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   virtual int CompareByInsertKey( Base* item )
   {
      return 1;
   }   
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
   virtual int CompareByInsertKey( Base* item )
   {
      return 2;
   }   
};

int main()
{
    Base* d1 = new Derived;
    Base* d2 = new Derived2;

    d1->CompareByInsertKey(d2); // This is a valid call
                                // but the argument is not of type Derived*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the function signatures to match you have to use Base* in CompareByInsertKey.  Unfortunately, that means you could pass a Derived as the parameter on a Derived2.  Maybe templates would work better for your app.

Try running the following example.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;



class Base {
public:
    string name;
    Base(string n) : name(n) {}
    virtual int CompareByInsertKey(Base* item_in_list) = 0;
    virtual string Name() { return name;  }

};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base("derived") {}
    int CompareByInsertKey(Base *item_in_list)
    {
        cout << "In Derived, parameter is " << item_in_list->Name() << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};


class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2() : Base("derived2") {}

    int CompareByInsertKey(Base *item_in_list)
    {
        cout << "In Derived2, parameter is " << item_in_list->Name() << endl;

        return 0;
    }

};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Base * d2 = new Derived2();
    Base *d = new Derived();
    d2->CompareByInsertKey(d);

    return 0;
}
```

KC

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a more complicated structure and knowledge about the types

```
class Base
{
public:
    int publicComparator(Base* instance)
    {
        // you can use either typeid() or your on enum that you put in the 
        // hierarchy
        if (typeid(this) == typeidf(instance))
        {
            return privateComparator(instance);
        }

        return ErrorCode;
    }

private:
    virtual privateComparator(Base *instance) = 0;
}

class Dervied : public Base {

private:
    privateComparator(Base* instance) override {
        // The assumption is privateComparator is only called when this cast
        // can sucessfully be completed
        Derived* derivedInstance = static_cast<Derived*>(instance);

        // Do functionality

        return result;
    }
}
```

So with this if you call `a->publicComparator(b)' only when the type of`a`and`b` are the same will the derived function actually be executed, is that the functionality that you where looking for ?